# C# detect when page load called from browser refresh not server control

Tags: c#

When the page load event in C# is executed is there a way of detecting whether it has been called from the user hitting refresh (or F5) on the browser or from a server control being clicked?
I want to tell when the last event was a page refresh (not a server control such as a button being clicked). Both events will raise a page reload but I have no way of telling whether it is from a browser refresh.

Comment: You can tell if its from a server contol using the [`IsPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Liam I think a refresh of  a previous postback will return true.

Comment: Can you also have a hidden field with randomly generated guid? Store it as a session variable or in a database after postback. If already found there it is an F5 refresh.

Comment: I tried using __EVENTTARGET when IsPostBack is true. That identifies the server control that triggered the postback but if I do a refresh from the browser the __EVENTTARGET returns the last control that was clicked. The problem is that the refresh icon on the browser page is not a server control so clicking on it does register as an event. It is also not part of the DOM of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using jquery to detect when an element on the body of the page has been clicked. It calls the function OnSubmit (using AJAX) in code behind which sets a C# variable "pagereresh" to false. The variable is set to true when it is declared at the top of the page.
In Pageload I check this variable and if it is false I know the event which caused the pageload was a button click on the page.If it is true I know it was a Page reload.In Page_Unload in C# I set this variable back to true.
The Jquery code is below:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
              // Check for left button
              if (e.button == 0) {

                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "Default.aspx/OnSubmit",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (response) {


                      },
                      failure: function (response) {

                      }
                  });
              }
          });
```